# Python logging JSON config for sub packages

Tags: python, json, logging, config

I have a set of Python scripts ordered like:

package1

- Y.py
- Z.py

package2

- log.py

where the log.py creates the central setup for all logging with:

```
logging_config_json_file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../logging.json")
parsed_logging_data = json.load(logging_config_json_file)
logging.config.dictConfig(parsed_logging_data)


def get_logger(logger_name):
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

This work if I get the loggers through a **package2.log.get_logger(__name__)** call.

But, I just cannot get the sub-packages package1.X and Y to be correctly configured in the logging.json file.

Here is a simple version of the JSON file:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": 0,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "package1.X": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": 0
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "WARN",
        "handlers": ["console"]
    }
}
```

Why isn't everything from package1.X here logged at INFO level (only the warnings are emitted)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much (kind of newbie), but it looks that level is cascaded from `root -> logger -> handler` or `root -> logger -> handler` (I don't have loggers yet.

So if you set **root** to INFO you should get:

- INFO on `package1.X`
- DEBUG on everything else

As I said, don't have explanation yet (maybe later when I spend more time with logging framework in python)